# Sorting by struct data inside unordered_map

Tags: c++, vector, time-complexity, unordered-map

I have an `std::unordered_map<id, town_data> data`, where town_data is a `struct` of different information - name (string), taxes collected (int) and distance from capital town (int). I'm supposed to build a `std::vector<id>`, which is sorted by beforementioned distance, lowest to high. I'm quite struggling to figure out how can this be done efficiently. I suppose I could simply loop through the `data`, create `std::map<distance, id>` through that loop/insertion, sort it by distance unless maps are sorted by default, and copy it key by key to new vector, `std::vector<id>`. But this seems really wasteful approach. Am I missing some shortcut or more efficient solution here?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I am very happy that you are helping. That is the whole purpose of this site.  It is a pity that I can only upvote once. Thank you anyway for your good contribution and supportive activity. I am not sure what I can do more. Thank you again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a `std::vector` of iterators into the map and then sort the iterators according to your sorting criteria. After sorting, you could transform the result into a `std::vector<id>`.

Create a `std::vector` of iterators:

```
    std::vector<decltype(data)::iterator> its;
    its.reserve(data.size());
    for(auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
        its.push_back(it);
```

Sort that `std::vector`:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::sort, std::transform

    std::sort(its.begin(), its.end(),
              [](auto& lhs, auto&rhs) {
                  return lhs->second.distance < rhs->second.distance;
              });
```

And finally, transform it into a `std::vector<id>`:

```
#include <iterator> // std::back_inserter

    std::vector<id> vec;
    vec.reserve(its.size());
    std::transform(its.begin(), its.end(), std::back_inserter(vec),
                   [](auto it) {
                       return it->first;
                   });
```

Comment: Thank you mate, I didn't even think of possibility of vectoring and sorting iterators itself. Very useful idea!

Comment: @JustAnotherDoomer Glad it helped! You're welcome!

Comment: Indeed the better answer. I would have put the map it in a multiset, by wasting memory. This is good +1

Answer (score 1):

I think that the vector of id can be sorted directly as below,

```
std::vector<decltype(decltype(data)::value_type::second_type::id)> vec;
vec.reserve(data.size());
for(auto it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); ++it)
    vec.push_back(it->second.id);
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&data](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return data[lhs].distance < data[rhs].distance; });
```

I'm wondering if is this more efficient than sorting a vector of town_data, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think anyone has suggested sorting a vector of `town_data`. Anyway, I would measure this. You'll have to do a lot of lookups in the map here and I wouldn't be surprised if that takes more time than using iterators when sorting. It may depend on the size of the map I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was not aware of how a lot of lookups in the map as you said. I'm so surprised and it makes me learn a lot.

Comment: It's just a suspicion. I would need to measure before saying anything about the performance for sure. I like the solution anyway because it's simple, but I don't get `decltype(decltype(data)::value_type::second_type::id`. The type is defined as `id` so why not use that?

Comment: It's just that I was not sure whether if is ```id``` a type or not, and I felt that it's better to use the type such like ```std::vector<decltype(data)::iterator>``` in preceding answer.